# Using WeakHashMap to Combat Data Loss/Concurrency Issues

Tags: java, minecraft

I am developing a program in Java that has clients that need to have data/properties/etc stored server side. I want to make sure that no data loss occurs when two different bits of code access the same client data, edit, and save.

My idea was to initially utilize a WeakHashMap with weak values. Essentially, whenever a thread/process/etc attempts to access a client data wrapper object, the user manager will check if the data object exists already in memory (which will happen if another bit of code is handling that user, or if the user is currently online). If it does not exist in memory, it will load from file, and store in a weak hash map, otherwise it will return the existing data object.

Essentially, I am trying to create a singleton-like system for each individual data file that exists, but for memory reasons, I still need to make sure that when each user is not in use, not to store them in memory.

I am just curious, is this a valid use for a weak hash map, or am I tackling the problem at the wrong angle? For reference, [here's the code](https://bitbucket.org/Blossomforth/simply-modular/src/048e5dda7af7fa395209c4244bb2433f50b9f772/src/me/corriekay/simplymodular/module/core/usermanager/UserManager.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#UserManager.java-111) that I'm talking about. (userCache is the weakhashmap in question). Admittedly, this is rather old code, but I'm rewriting the project from the ground up for another platform, so I figured if I am doing it wrong, I might as well do it right while I have the chance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are using Guava at your project? If yes - it has a perfect component for your case: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be in need of an LRUCache (LRU = Least Recently Used) on which you specify the amount of elements you keep in map. After each insert, a check is made to decide wether to remover or not the least recently accessed element. There are many implementations out there. This is a simple one with a plain LinkedHashMap:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
  private int cacheSize;

  public LRUCache(int cacheSize) {
    super(16, 0.75, true);
    this.cacheSize = cacheSize;
  }

  protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
    return size() >= cacheSize;
  }
}
```

The linked hash map in this case will keep an order of the hash map based on access, as specified by the constructor that takes 3 arguments. Then the "removeEldestEntry" implementation simply checks that if the size has gotten bigger enough, then the eldest (in this case the least accessed) element on the map can be removed.